# Sending the first message from a chrome extension background script to the content script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, message

Every way I've seen it done requires first sending a message from the content script to the background script, and using the tab id from receiving that message on the background side to pass a response to the content side.

There's one method using chrome.tabs.query to get the active tab id and send a message to the content script, but I get

`Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

when I use this approach. I need to trigger a content script method from the background script, by sending a message from the background script (/actually evaluating javascript in the background page context via puppeteer). Are there any solutions here?